# Guardar valores especificos de um ficheiro

Tags: c

Conteudo do ficheiro:

df:bd:89:f1:d4:53 50 20.0

76:1f:02:8f:7d:c8 75 15.0

37:77:ac:10:4e:de 90 -10.5

21:33:ac:63:f7:cd 60 30.0

79:fa:3d:ca:4b:3a 65 25.5

bb:7c:72:ab:ad:ce 35 -5.5

22:db:ed:73:a7:4c 95 20.0

a5:05:92:fa:47:cb 85 35.0

c6:9d:7b:7a:3e:91 15 -25.5

e4:58:0e:30:c2:cf 70 45.5

como consigo guardar os valores a frente dos codigos hexadecimais numa variavel(ou seja como posso dar skip do reading dos codigos hexadecimais).

Comment: Você quer guardar todos os dados que se seguem ao primeiro espaço? Sempre serão 2 valores ou esta quantidade de valores pode variar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o exemplo de entrada fornecido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE arq;
    float a, b;
    arq = fopen("ficheiro.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(arq, "%*s %f %f", &a, &b) != EOF)
        printf("t%f\t%f\n", a, b);
    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

Note o `%*s` no formato que indica para o `scanf` ignorar esta entrada, no caso a primeira, não atribuindo a nada.